# lxml xpath and find return nothing

Tags: python, lxml

Python 2.7

I assume I'm missing something incredibly basic having to do with lxml but I have no idea what it is. By way of background, I have not used lxml much before but have used Xpaths extensively in Selenium and have also done a bit of parsing with BS4.

So, I'm making a call to this API that returns some XML as a string. Easy enough:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

myXML = 'xml here'
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(myXML))
print tree.xpath('/IKnowThisTagExistsInMyXML')
```

It always returns [] or None. I've tried tree.find() and tree.findall() as well, to no avail.

I'm hoping someone has seen this before and can tell me what's going on.

Comment: Please post your xml

Comment: try following:-
`tree.xpath('//IKnowThisTagExistsInMyXML')`

Answer (score 0):

By using an XPath of `/IKnowThisTagExistsInMyXML` this *assumes* the tag `IKnowThisTagExistsInMyXML` is at the top-level of your XML Document; which I really *doubt* it is.

Trying search your XMl Document for this tag instead by doing:

```
print tree.xpath('//*/IKnowThisTagExistsInMyXML')
```

See: [XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)